# info window not showing

Tags: android, google-maps

This is really killing me, I had them working then rewrote a bunch of code, and now it doesn't and I've got no version control!  Any help is appreciated.

I create the markers in a Utility class.

```
    private static MarkerOptions buildAmarker(LatLng location, String bankType, String locationDetails,
                                          float markerColour) {

    MarkerOptions binMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(bankType)
            .snippet(locationDetails)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(markerColour));
    //.snippet(siteName + " | " + locationDetails);
    return binMarker;enter code here
```

Then after my Loader completes, onLoadFinish, it hands me back various list of marker Options objects, I process them into Markers here:

```
    private List<Marker> addBankListToMap(List<MarkerOptions> oneBankList) {
    Log.i("ADDING a selected", "banks list to map");
    // we need to save NEW lists of map attached markers OR can't change marker visibility
    List<Marker> newBankList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < oneBankList.size(); i++) {
        MarkerOptions binMarker = oneBankList.get(i);
        Marker newMarker = m_map.addMarker(binMarker);
        newMarker.setVisible(true);
        newBankList.add(newMarker);
        //Log.e("!!!addingBank", newMarker.getTitle() + newMarker.getSnippet());
    }
    return newBankList;
```

Then end onLoadFinish with this

```
// setup click event for home marker to launch change home screen
    m_map.setOnMarkerClickListener(EarthquakeActivity.this);
```

But none of the info windows appear if clicked.  What am I missing?  It was working till I rewrote my code, and I made a LOT of algorthmic improvements, I use arrays instead of half a dozen hashmaps, so the memory overhead should be less.

I can only think I've either deleted something crucial in a tidy up while being tired.
OR
I've blocked the info windows somehow.  Some sleuthing to find the block, by disabling the changes, has failed.  So it seems I've deleted something, forgotten something vital.

What do I need to do to get infoWindows working again?  This is absolutely vital to my app.  Arrggg!

```
    @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if (marker.equals(homeMarkerFinal)) {
        // TODO make this launch the change home address screen
        Log.wtf("markerClicked", "!!!!");
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(EarthquakeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is just for a single marker, the home marker.  All the other markers are unnamed, I've got around 4000 markers stored in Lists as MarkerOptions.  These lists are passed to addBankListToMap as oneBankList and converted into Markers, and attached to the map.

Comment: pls show onMarkerClick that you implement

Comment: Hey phongvan, thanks for your attention!  

Do you think I could be missing something there?  I have about 4000 markers, and don't keep individual references to each, I just have them all shoved in 5 lists, each list contains Markers of a different colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show inforwindow you need call:

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Pls put in in your `onMarkerClick` function.

Comment: You're an absolute star. :)

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant phongvan!, of course at some point I deleted this

```
    else {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
```

onMarkerClick.

Thankgod!  My app had become useless! :)  A thousand thanks phongvan.